# How to post http request using digest authentication with libcurl

Tags: c, libcurl, digest

I'm trying to perform a post request and I'm trying to do it with the digest authentication. with `libcurl`, I set the options:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);

curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

before setting all the other option (post, url and everything). The server closes my connection and I think that no digest is made. I just don't know how to automatically obtain the challenge-response behaviour of the digest. If I set `HTTPAUTH` to `CURLAUTH_BASIC` it *encodes* the stuff, I see with the VERBOSE option the header containing `authorization = basic`. With digest no headers.

Do you know how can I do it, or can you give me some example? I really searched everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

For a basic `POST` request you should do:

```
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

For a multipart `POST` (a.k.a `multipart/form-data`):

```
struct curl_httppost *post;
struct curl_httppost *postend;
/* setup your POST body with `curl_formadd(&post, &postend, ...)` */
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

Pro-tip: use `curl` command-line tool with `--libcurl request.c`: it outputs into this C file the list of options used to perform the corresponding request.

Comment: I tried, but it does not work properly...I should receive the challenge and I don't receive anything, do I have to write more code after the code you send me? do I have to set headers or something similar?

Comment: Then you should have a problem server-side. Of course you must set the `CURLOPT_URL` option, but otherwise this is all that you need. And I do confirm it works (e.g see these [real world examples](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-api/blob/master/moodstocks-api/msapi.c)). Once again I do recommend you to perform the same request on the command-line, on your own service, with the `--libcurl out.c` option: it will output everything you need.

Comment: Yeah! now it works! It was a problem of the server as you suggest. I thank you so much my friend, have a good day.

Comment: @Gioia it seems you found this answer useful, if so you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).